# create custom main from dll

Tags: c++, dll, program-entry-point, getmessage

I'm creating a layer around .NET and Win API. I need to prepare some things before the users can enter the main function, like calling the `GetMessage` function.

Is it possible to start a program from a dll, which than calls a custom main function on a separate thread?

It would be easer if I would let `GetMessage` run on a different thread, but as soon as I call `SetWindowsHookEx` for `WH_MOUSE_LL` on the main threat, the mouse slows down tremendously for almost a minute as if I haven't called `GetMessage` at all. But when I debug in Visual Studio, it does enter `GetMessage`, so that can't be the problem.

Hope someone can help.

**UPDATE**

this is what I'm trying to achieve.

user_source(cpp)

```
include MyDLL
custom main(this main is defined by a user)
{

}
```

MyDLL (cpp)

```
main(real starting point of the application)
{
    set the windows hooks
    call the main defined by the user on a different thread
    message loop
}
```

Comment: Its not very clear what you are asking here.  If you start a program from a DLL, you'd be starting a process.  Unless you are loading another dll in which case you can call any function in it you like?

Comment: `Main` is the first function to be called in every process. Of course there are OS-specific sequences that have to be taken, before `main` can be run. How about an intermediate process as a boot-helper?

Comment: @bash.d Not fully true, if you have C++, the constructors of "global" objects are called before main executes. But then gain like Pete, I don't get the gist of the question.

Comment: @rioki Yes, I know, but that can't be the intention...

Comment: sorry for not being clear.